Is there a way to determine whether symmetric group $S_{n}$ has a subgroup of order $m$？
I'm interested in whether $S_{n}$ has a subgroup of order $m$. And as we know, $m | n!$ has to be hold, but it is not a sufficient condition. I have researched some other cases.
If $m \le n$, then cyclic group $C_{m}$ is valid.
If $n=\sum_{i=1}^{k} {p_{i}}$, then $m= lcm(p_{1},p_{2} \dots p_{k})$ is valid, since we can construct such cyclic group.
If $n=\sum_{i=1}^{k} {p_{i}}$, and for each $p_{i}$, there is a subgroup of $S_{p_{i}}$ of order $q_{i}$, then $m = \prod_{i=1}^{k} {q_{i}}$ is valid by using the direct product of these groups.
These can not cover all the cases, since $S_{5}$ has a subgroup of order $20$ but in none of these cases.
I have also tried to use the Schreier-Sims algorithm, but I find it hard to construct a group with fixed stabilizer and fixed size of orbit.
Are there some other ways or some other related works?

This is equivalent to classifying which orders of finite group act faithfully on a set of size $n$ which is quite complicated. There is a "dual" problem which is to ask, given a group $G$, what the smallest size of a set on which $G$ acts faithfully is (hence the smallest symmetric group into which it embeds), which is also quite complicated.
